# Prevent duplicate items in bindingsource

Tags: c#

In this code i have a datagridview and the datasource of the datagridview is a bindingsource. When i insert a item in my datagridview it is possible to add it 2 times so i get duplicate items in the bindingsource.

How can i prevent duplicate items in my bindingsource?"

this is the code i use:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            class GridItem
            {
                public int Ordernummer { get; set; }
                public int Bonnummer { get; set; }
                public int Volgnummer { get; set; }
                public string Bewerking { get; set; }
            }

            List<GridItem> gridItems;
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                gridItems = new List<GridItem>{
                    new GridItem{ Ordernummer = 123456, Bonnummer = 1, Volgnummer = 40, Bewerking = "1130-Lasersnijden"},
                    new GridItem{ Ordernummer = 123678, Bonnummer = 2, Volgnummer = 30, Bewerking = "1130-Lasersnijden"}
                };

                bs.DataSource = gridItems;

                dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;

                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
                dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
//ADD ITEMS
                gridItems.Add(new GridItem{ Ordernummer = 123456, Bonnummer = 1, Volgnummer = 40, Bewerking = "1130-Lasersnijden"});
                bs.ResetBindings(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note:**
The data in the datagridview is hardcoded now, in the furture i will load the data in from a database.

Comment: use .Distinct() in your list before binding to grid

Comment: Would still depend on the generated hashcode and equals method. I would be a class that implements GridItem and override these methods.

Comment: @VinaySingh Can you give me a example?

Comment: If you get data from a database, you can always write your DB query in a way to avoid duplicates. If your concern is about users inserting duplicates, just check for the key before inserting into your binding source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***List.Contains*** method to check if element exists before you add it to the list.

***List.Contains*** metohod internally uses the **Equals** method of the Objects already in the List, if they implements the interface IEquatable.

So, you would need to make your class GridItem to extends IEquatable.

Then, override method Equals as following (on GridItem class):

```
class GridItem : IEquatable<GridItem>
    {
        public int Ordernummer { get; set; }
        public int Bonnummer { get; set; }
        public int Volgnummer { get; set; }
        public string Bewerking { get; set; }

        //This method must return true if the current GridItem and the passed as parameter are the same
        public bool Equals(GridItem gridItem)
        {
            //What does a GridItem to be the same than other?
            //If it's just Ordernummer, as easy like:
            return this.Ordernummer == gridItem.Ordernummer;
        }
    }
```

And then, on your adding method:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ADD ITEMS
    var gridToAdd = new GridItem{ Ordernummer = 123456, Bonnummer = 1, Volgnummer = 40, Bewerking = "1130-Lasersnijden"};
    if(!gridItems.Contains(gridToAdd){
        gridItems.Add(gridToAdd);
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
    }
}
```

However, if you just need to use Ordernummer property to check if element exists you can juts use:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!gridItems.Any(gridItem => gridItem.Ordernummer == 123456){
        gridItems.Add(new GridItem{ Ordernummer = 123456, Bonnummer = 1, Volgnummer = 40, Bewerking = "1130-Lasersnijden"});
        bs.ResetBindings(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your awnser, but i dont quite get the idea. Can you maybe expant your awnser. I dont quite understand what the equals function qould look like

Comment: How would i use the equals funtion you have? I dont see it anywhere

Comment: This method `gridItems.Contains(gridToAdd)` uses it by default to check if element already exists. It iterates over all the elements on _gridItems_ using _Equals_ function to compare.

Comment: Alright i thyiunk i get it now but how can i extend the griditem class so it works? If i know that i think it will work at my side, Again thanks for the help

Comment: Updated with more details on the Equals definition for GridItem class